# In-App purchase,One payment, two callbacks

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I'm using the storekit2 API to handle the payment process, but I'm running into a problem. After making only one payment request (product.purchase()), the user receives two callbacks: first a synchronous callback and then an asynchronous callback (listening for Transaction.updates). The interval between two callbacks is less than one minute. The transactionid in the order ticket is different, but the appaccounttoken is the same. The probability of this problem occurring is very small, about 1 in 10,000. The iOS version that appeared was also 15-16-17. Does anyone else have the same problem as me?

```
let appAccountToken = UUID()
let result = try await product.purchase(options: [.appAccountToken(appAccountToken)])
switch result {
      case .success(let verification):
      //A successful callback order was received 
      //do something other
      await transaction.finish()
      break
default:
      break
}
 
private func listenForTransactions() -> Task<Void, Error> {
        return Task.detached{
          
            for await result in Transaction.updates {
         
                do {
                    let transaction = try self.checkVerified(result)
                    //A successful callback order was received again
                } catch {

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I can't reproduce this bug. According to our log report, it is confirmed that only one payment was initiated. I do not know where the second successful order came from, and the order verification was passed. Did the player actually pay twice? Is there anyone in the same situation as me?